# How to get script variable value into php

Tags: php, wordpress

```
    <tr class="form-field">
    <th valign="top" scope="row">
    <label for="email"><?php _e('E-Mail', 'custom_table_example')?></label>
        </th>
         <td>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" style="width: 95%" value="<?php echo esc_attr($item['email'])?>"
               size="50" class="code" placeholder="<?php _e('Your E-Mail', 'custom_table_example')?>" onchange="myFunction();"  required>
         </td>
</tr>

   <?php
echo'<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("email").value;
alert(x);
}             
</script>';
?>
<?php
$content = "<script>document.write(x)</script>";
echo $content;
?>
<?php
 $user = get_user_by( 'email', 'abc@a.com' );
 $userId = $user->ID;

echo "That E-mail is registered to user number " . $userId;

?>
```

---

How to get javascript variable into php?? 
      I have tried with the above code .I am getting javascript alert but i need the variable value in php.
     If i get variable need to compare with userid . If userid exists i need to store it in to db else it should not save into db and give an error message.... Need to check before submit.
    Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: PHP is server side, Javascript in client side, Server side executes first and is unaware of client side changes unless you call it externally like AJAX

Answer (score 0):

you are confused about how server side languages work.

any php that exists in the page is processed by the server before the resulting HTML is returned to the client.  Because of this, javascript cannot talk to the server in the way you have tried.

What you need to do is use javascript (probably with jquery) to send an ajax request to the server, this will send the data to the server and wait for an answer, you can then do something based upon that answer.

Here is an example of an ajax call (from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)):

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```